# C++ operator== and user-defined type casts

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a class named uniVal with defined conversion to int_64 double and string. When I try to compare object of this class to int GCC says:
candidates are:

```
operator==(int, int) <built-in>
operator==(int64_t {aka long int}, int) <built-in>
operator==(unsigned int, int) <built-in>
operator==(long unsigned int, int) <built-in>
operator==(float, int) <built-in>
operator==(double, int) <built-in>
error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘uniVal’ and ‘int’)
```

but if i specify cast to double to be explicit it compiles. Is it possible to make gcc choose conversion type closest to other arguments type?

UPD:
writing own operator== for each type combination will, offcourse, solve this, but it i want this class to work wit all c++ types, so i would like to only write a bunch of conversion functions and make complier do the rest.

Comment: If you wrote your own `operator==(uniVal, int)` and `operator==(int, uniVal)`, that should solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to make gcc choose conversion type closest to other arguments type?

Short version: No, because in overload resolution, the relation of each of the parameters' types are not considered.

Long version:

The compiler finds all viable functions (that is, all functions that can theoretiaclly be called with the given parameters via conversion or directly) and ranks them against each other. Overload resolution succeeds if and only if exactly one of the viable functions is strictly better than all others. A precise listing of how functions are compared against each other is available [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) (section "Best viable function"). For this particular case, only the following is relevant:

> F1 is determined to be a better function than F2 if implicit conversions for all arguments of F1 are not worse than the implicit conversions for all arguments of F2, and [...] there is at least one argument of F1 whose implicit conversion is better than the corresponding implicit conversion for that argument of F2 [...]

The remaining rules are not applicable in your context because the return type for each of the operators is the same and they are not templates (or specializations thereof). 
Also, your second operand requires no conversion either way (in the subset of overloads present in your question), so it's all about the conversion of `uniVal` to `long` and `double` and the following numeric promotions/conversions.

The conversion sequences to each are ranked according to the following (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion); section "Ranking of implicit conversion sequences"):

1. **Exact Match:** no conversion required, lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, qualification conversion, user-defined conversion of class type to the same class
2. **Promotion:** integral promotion, floating-point promotion
3. **Conversion:** integral conversion, floating-point conversion, floating-integral conversion, pointer conversion, pointer-to-member conversion, boolean conversion, user-defined conversion of a derived class to its base

In your case, both `long int` and `double` require no additional conversions in addition to your user-defined conversion. Thus, they are ranked equally to each other (but are better than the other candidates which *would* require additional conversions). Thus, your call is ambiguous.

You'll notice that there is no point at which the different parameters' types are compared. This is (not?) done for a good reason: after all, the parameters may not be used in conjunction with one another at all in the function body (realistically, they will be in `operator==`, but for the compiler this is just a function like all others) in which case comparing their types would not provide any useful information whatsoever.

Comment: I realize this left the scope of the question somewhat. I missed a little detail about what was asked until I was mostly done writing this so I figured I'd just finish what I started.

Comment: Well, I found this information pretty useful, so thanks